# How to Change color of Dark action bar at night mode?

Tags: android, theming, android-night-mode

I treid to change the background color of the Action bar to another color istead of the default color.
I am using :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

... values/styles.xml:

```
    <resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryLightColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

...and:night/colors.xml

```
<color name="primaryDarkColor">#430F58</color>
<color name="primaryColor">#F7F2F8</color>
<color name="secondaryColor">#9e9e9e</color>
<color name="secondaryDarkColor">#707070</color>
<color name="primaryTextColor">#eceff1</color>
<color name="activityBackground">#121212</color>
```

...mainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)

    }[enter image description here][1]
}
```

ll works great,but the color of my action bar remaimining black all time.

Can you help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try `<item name="colorSurface">@color/someColor</item>` in your dark mode theme.

Answer (score 2):

If you want ActionBar color be same when Dark Mode and Usual mode.
You can use

```
supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.color.color))
```

In OnCreate()

Answer (score 0):

I use `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"` in layout

Comment: This only changes the background for the layout and not the actionbar